# ApacheBeam python count how many orders below 15, how many above or equal, k = count v = sum

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am reading from a .csv, I split and grab only the last value.
I convert the string to float
I compare if less than 15, and append to lessthanList value,
else, append to morethanList

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

orders = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/whatever/taxiorders.csv'


class tellingApart(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    element = float(element.split(",")[-1])
    lessthanlist = []
    morethan_list = []
    if element < 15:
      lessthanlist.append(element)
    else:
      morethan_list.append(element)
    lessthankey = len(lessthanlist)
    lessthanvalue = sum(lessthanlist)
    morethankey = len(morethan_list)
    morethanvalue = sum(morethan_list)
    return lessthankey,lessthanvalue,morethankey,morethanvalue


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  (p
   | ReadFromText(orders, skip_header_lines=2)
   | beam.ParDo(tellingApart())
   | beam.Map(print))
```

sample [file](https://storage.googleapis.com/apache-beam-samples/nyc_taxi/misc/sample1000.csv)

I was expecting to get only K,V I'm messing up, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText


class tellingApart(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        element = float(element.split(",")[-1])
        lessthanlist = []
        morethan_list = []
        if element < 15:
            lessthanlist.append(element)
        else:
            morethan_list.append(element)
        lessthankey = len(lessthanlist)
        lessthanvalue = sum(lessthanlist)
        morethankey = len(morethan_list)
        morethanvalue = sum(morethan_list)
        return [[lessthankey, lessthanvalue, morethankey, morethanvalue]]


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    (
        p
        | beam.Create(["test,10", "test,20"])
        | beam.ParDo(tellingApart())
        | beam.Map(print)
    )
```

Output:

```
[1, 10.0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 20.0]
```